# Rewrite in location, to a proxy_pass for a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I have a .conf file on my NGINX reverse proxy.
I'm getting a request URL like:
http://www.example.com/messaging

And I need to get it to transform /messaging into /system/console, to a karaf container.
It seems simple, but it is not, I'll explain it better why.

The container is in a different subdomain, like
http://subdomain.local.example.com/system/console

The only way I could get it to work it doesn't load any static files (images, js, css), only html, was like this:

```
location /messaging {
expires -1;
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
rewrite /messaging/(.*) /$1 last;
proxy_pass http://subdomain.local.example.com/system/console/;
}
```

This way above, images are requested at http://subdomain.local.example.com/system/console/res/flags/en.gif
instead of messaging/system/console/res/flags/en.gif.

Here is my full config file (unfortunately, indentation is not correct  here, I can assure it's correct on config file):

```
upstream app-web-dev-lb {
server app-web-dev-01:8080;
server app-web-dev-02:8080;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name app-dev.example.com;

client_max_body_size 50M;

location /my-services {
expires -1;
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
proxy_pass http://app-cm-dev.local.example.com/my-services;
}

location /app-messaging {
expires -1;
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';

#rewrite /app-messaging/(.*) /system/console/$1 break;
#rewrite /system/console/(.*) /app-messaging/$1 break;
#rewrite /app-messaging/(.*) /$1 last;
rewrite /app-messaging/(.*) /$1 break;
#rewrite /system/console/res/(.*) /app-messaging/res/$1 last;
#rewrite /app-messaging/res/(.*) /system/console/res/$1 last;
#rewrite /app-web(.*) /$1 last;

#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#proxy_set_header Host $host;
#proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

#proxy_pass http://servicemix-dev.local.example.com/system/console;
#proxy_pass http://servicemix-dev.local.example.com/system/console/bundles;
proxy_pass http://servicemix-dev.local.example.com\;

#proxy_redirect /system/console /app-messaging/system/console;
#proxy_redirect default;
#proxy_redirect off;
#proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location / {
expires -1;
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
rewrite /app-web(.*) /$1 last;
proxy_pass http://app-web-dev-lb/app-web/;
}

location /app-web {
expires -1;
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
rewrite /app-web(.*) /$1 last;
proxy_pass http://app-web-dev-lb/app-web/;
}
}
```

As a final note, I don't want to redirect /messaging to /, because I have a default / address which already redirects to other path.
So I don't want to add a /system location, as I'll have more Kafka containers.
I would like to understand why all requests aren't recognized inside the /messaging location, why some are redirected to /system/console/.....

Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Best regards,
Luis Nabais

Comment: Are you trying to pass `http://www.example.com/messaging/foo` to `http://subdomain.local.example.com/system/console/foo`?

Comment: Hello Richard. Thank you for your answer :)

Yes, the idea is exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the URI from `/messaging/foo` to `/system/console/foo` as it passes upstream in two ways.

Method one uses the `location` and `proxy_pass` directives to make the translation. For example:

```
location /messaging {
    expires -1;
    add_header ...;
    proxy_pass http://subdomain.local.example.com/system/console;
}
```

Both the URI on the `location` and `proxy_pass` statements should have a trailing `/`, or neither have a trailing `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

---

Method two uses a `rewrite...break`. For example:

```
location /messaging {
    expires -1;
    add_header ...;
    rewrite /messaging(/.*)?$ /system/console$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://subdomain.local.example.com;
}
```

You must use a `break` as the rewritten URI needs to be processed within the same `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. But on both ways, somehow the URL is rewritten and the /messaging part is ignored, so static files don't open correctly, they are opened like this:
http://www.example.com/system/console/res/flags/en.gif instead of http://www.example.com/messaging/system/console/res/flags/en.gif.

Comment: Somehow it's being redirected to /, which gets captured by the location /.